# Meaning of ひらっと

Tags: translation, onomatopoeia, grammar

銀河鉄道の夜から.

> 電燈の向こう側の暗い小路から出て来て、 **ひらっと**ジョバンニとすれちがいました.

Dictionary says flat, plain, may be it can be coldly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ひら doesn't mean 平(flat, plain) but ひらり.

Dictionaries say ひらり means

1: すばやく身をかわしたり飛び移ったりするさま。「ひらりと馬に飛び乗る」

2: 物が軽くひるがえるさま。「木の葉がひらりと舞い落ちる」

ひらっと is almost the same as ひらりと, which means "lightly", "nimbly".

Answer (score 3):

「ひらっと」 is not a very common onomatopoeic adverb to use in the context of passing by someone.  It would, however, mean "**casually**", "**quickly**", etc.

More commonly, you would encounter  「さっと」、「さーっと」、「すっと」、「すーっと」、「ふらっと」, etc.

Not sure what dictionary you use, but 「ひらっと」 just could ***not*** mean "flat or "plain" in the context.  You would not pass by someone "flat(ly)" or "plain(ly)", would you?

"Coldly" sounds off to me as well for the context.